# Where is located sp_msreplcheck_publish stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

`sp_msreplcheck_publish` is a sp that checks if you have sufficient rights to run a statement to alter a published table (transactional replication).

Trying to alter a published table without elevated rights fires trigger `tr_MStran_altertable` that calls `sp_MStran_ddlrepl` that execute `sp_msreplcheck_publish`. It returns correctly :

> Only members of the sysadmin fixed server role or db_owner fixed
>   database role can perform this operation.

The mystery for me  is that I cannot find this sp in published database or in master. Is it generated on demand?

Comment: This kB talks about drop and I am not sure if this also applies alter table. [FIX: Error 21050 when you remove a table that is not part of a publication in SQL Server 2014 or 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3209459/fix-error-21050-when-you-remove-a-table-that-is-not-part-of-a-publicat).

Comment: The stored procedure is executed indeed an it is not an issue. My question is where is it stored?

Answer (score 5):

If is hidden from general view but, if you connect using a [Dedicated Administrator Connection](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/08/dedicated-admin-connection-why-want-when-need-how-tell-whos-using/), you can see it in `master` via:

```
USE [master];
GO

SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(N'sys.sp_msreplcheck_publish'));
```

Not sure what you need to see the definition for, though, or why knowing where it is stored will help you accomplish anything. It's really this simple, and you can't change it, regardless of where it is stored:

```
create procedure sys.sp_MSreplcheck_publish 
as
begin
    --
    -- Do the sysadmin check first as it is 4 times more efficient
    -- than is_member call and reduces performance overhead in case 
    -- the user has sysadmin privileges
    --    
    if    is_srvrolemember('sysadmin') = 1 or
        is_member ('db_owner') = 1
    begin
        return (0)
    end
    else
    begin
        raiserror (21050, 14, -1)
        return (1)
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. My question is answered and my curiosity satisfied now that I know that there are hidden sp and the way to see them.